OOPS: cannot read user list file:/etc/vsftpd.user_list error with VSFTP using MySQL as user backend
I want to set up a VSFTP server in Ubuntu 22.04.4 with MySQL as a backend to store the users.
I've used this guide to set it up (it's for CentOS but except for the part on pam_mysql.so it's the applicable to Ubuntu).
Here is my setup:

/etc/vsftpd.conf

anonymous_enable=NO
pasv_addr_resolve=YES
pasv_address=ftp.company.com
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=41000

local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES

nopriv_user=vsftpd
chroot_local_user=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
user_sub_token=$USER
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
#user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd_user_conf
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
pasv_enable=YES


/etc/pam.d/vsftpd

#%PAM-1.0
session       optional        pam_keyinit.so       force revoke
auth required pam_mysql.so user=vsftpd passwd=mypassword  host=localhost db=vsftpd table=accounts usercolumn=username   passwdcolumn=pass crypt=3
account required pam_mysql.so user=vsftpd passwd=mypassword host=localhost db=vsftpd table=accounts usercolumn=username  passwdcolumn=pass crypt=3


MySQL accounts table

mysql> select * from accounts;
+----+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| id | username                          | pass                             |
+----+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | user@company.com                  | [passwordhash]                   |
+----+-----------------------------------+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


On a local test server in virtualbox & all is working fine, however when I use the same configuration on the production server, I got this error upon connecting to the FTP server with winSCP:
OOPS: cannot read user list file:/etc/vsftpd.user_list

So apparently vsftp is not using the mysql connection to retrieve the users but is looking for a userlist file which is missing off course.
So far I've checked the following:

Verified libpam-mysql & mysql-client is installed
Make sure I'm able to connect to mysql db using the vsftpd credentials
Disabled iptables so this won't interfere with the connection to the database

But so far I haven't been able to solve this problem. The frustrating bit is that It's working on my virtualbox instance but I cannot see any difference between this instance & the production instance.
How can I troubleshoot the connection between vsftpd & MySQL please?
My production environment:

Ubuntu 22.04.4
MySQL 8.0.36
vsftpd 3.0.5
iptables v1.8.7


Upon further investigation I've noticed the following error in /var/log/auth.log
pam_mysql - MySQL error (Access denied for user 'vsftpd'@'localhost' (using password: YES))

Like I've tought, vsftpd cannot connect to the mysql database. I think I've solved it by creating a new user: vsftpd_user & new database vsftpd_db and recreating the grants & tables for vsftpd. I did not have any further problems connecting vsftpd to mysql in this way so probably there was some confusion by using the same name for db/user.
